# Replacing the default id with an unsigned integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 7
```

By default, Rails 7 generates migrations, with the id set to bigint (I am using MySQL).

What I would like to do, is have it generate an unsigned integer (preferably bigint) instead.

I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
class CreateAuthors < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :authors, id: false do |t|
      t.unsinged_integer :id, primary_key: true, null: false
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :first
      t.string :last
      t.string :pseudonym 
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run:

```
rake:db migrate
```

I get a long string of error messages, and the last is pointing to line 4:

```
      t.unsinged_integer :id, primary_key: true, null: false
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any ideas?

Solution: typo it's unsigned_integer not unsinged_integer

Comment: The column type (and method) is called `unsigned_integer` (notice the order of `g` and `n`).

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to make this unsigned bigint?

Comment: You can use something like `t.bigint :id, unsigned: true, primary_key: true, null: false`. However, even a signed bigint can take that large values, it just shouldn't matter...

Comment: You'll have to explicitly set the types both here and and on any foreign keys that reference it... and to accomplish what exactly?

Comment: @max IDs are never negative. Why would I waste half the address space? Yes, of course foreign ids must match. Why would that be a problem?

Comment: Its not really enough of a problem IMHO to warrant the use of your time.